# Share data/params between child tabs on Ionic2 (Angular2)

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-tabs

Having an app with tabs, I need to share data between them.
So in the first tab I do `public static data= {};`
Then on the second tab I import the first page and get data using `FirstTab.data`.

Is this considered wrong?
Is there a better way to share data/params between child tabs? (not from parent to child)

Comment: you could set it in a common service. That is the general way

Comment: Also, you can use `localStorage` for this.

Comment: Thank you both, I know about these options but still, are these better than the way I used and if yes, why.